# How can I count elements with using timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, counter

I have a timestamp value in my table and it's set to on update current timestamp.

It updates itself when user is doing x work.

I want to count how many users did x work in last 30 minutes. What's the mysql query that I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [count](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) aggregate function your query

```
select 
    count(timestampColumnName) 
from 
    yourtable 
where 
    timestampColumnName>date_sub(now(), interval 30 minute)
    // and any other conditions as needed
```